# Extra escape character in go URL

Tags: url, go

I have the following snippet of code :

```
    u := *baseURL
    u.User = nil 
    if q := strings.Index(path, "?"); q > 0 { 
            u.Path = path[:q]
            u.RawQuery = path[q+1:]
    } else {
            u.Path = path
    }   

    log.Printf(" url %v, u.String())
```

I see that when the baseurl is set to something like this http://localhost:9000/buckets/test%?bucket_uuid=7864b0dcdf0a578bd0012c70aef58aca the url package seems to add an extra escape character near the % sign. For e.g. the output of the above print statement is the following :

```
2015/03/25 12:02:49  url http://localhost:9000/pools/default/buckets/test%2525?bucket_uuid=7864b0dcdf0a578bd0012c70aef58aca
```

This seems to only happen when the RawQuery field of the URL is set. Any idea why this is happening ?  I'm using go version 1.3.3

Cheers,
Manik

Comment: With "an extra", do you mean you get `%2525` instead of expected `%25`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URLs may only contain characters of the ASCII character set, but it is often intended to include/transfer characters outside of this ASCII set. In such cases the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

If the *raw* URL contains characters outside of the allowed set, they are escaped: they are replaced with a `'%'` followed by two hexadecimal digits. Therefore the character `'%'` is special and also has to be escaped (and its escaped form will start with `'%'` as well, and its hexadecimal code is `25`).

Since your *raw* URL contains the character `'%'`, it will be replaced by `"%25"`.

Back to your example: in the printed form you see `"%2525"`. You could ask why not just `"%25"`?

This is because your original url contains a `'%'` in its *escaped* form which means its *raw* form contains the escape sequence `"%25"`. If you use/interpret this as *raw* input, the `'%'` will be replaced by `"%25"` which will be followed by the `"25"` from the input hence resulting in `"%2525"`.

See: [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Also: [RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html)

And also: [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html)